# Where are the namespaces in visual studio

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, namespaces

I am new to Visual Studio and C#. I went through the tutorials on C# and all the sample programs I went through, were written inside namespaces. But when I used a template on Visual Studio, all the predefined codes weren't inside namespaces. Shouldn't the classes in the programs be in namespaces? Why aren't they present by default? Should I define them?

Thanks!

[edit]
Below is the code in one of the files that doesn't have a namespace.

```
using System;   
using System.Web.Security;  

public partial class Login : System.Web.UI.Page  
{   
    protected void btnSubmit_Click( object sender, EventArgs e )  
    {  
        // Note: Add code to validate user name, password. This code is for illustrative purpose only.  
        // Do not use it in production environment.          
        FormsAuthentication.RedirectFromLoginPage( txtUserName.Text, false );  
    }  
}
```

Comment: Could you show a section of block of code that you are saying doesn't have an namespace? Could help with an explanation.

Comment: do a msdn google search on `C# namespace examples` this will show you how to use them as well as how they work[C# MSDN namespace](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z2kcy19k.aspx)

Comment: Namespaces are not required. However, you should always have one to avoid name clashes.

Comment: As you can see the partial keyword,I guess the other part of the Login class def would be in some namespace. And that would be the namespace of the Login class.

Answer (score 4):

There is a default namespace declared in your Project's properties. But it's a good practice to declare it explicitly.
If your project has no folders, all classes are inside the same namespace so it is redundant.

Comment: Hey, I am using Visual Studio 2010. I can't find any default namespaces in the properties windows. Is it where you meant it was?

Comment: Right-Click the Project > Select "Properties" > select "Application" tab at the left > See a text box labelled "Default namespace"

Answer (score 1):

A namespace is designed for providing a way to keep one set of names separate from another. The class names declared in one namespace does not conflict with the same class names declared in another. Please refer https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z2kcy19k.aspx for more details.

Answer (score 0):

### General

Namespaces are basically just a way to group your classes and give your Project a structure.

**Classnames must be unique for each namespace.**

You can also sort of "encapsulate" your Namespaces. For Example you can create some Namespaces  `SomeProject`, `SomeProject.Core` and `SomeProject.UI`

If you wite `using SomeProject.` the Intellisense would now suggest `Core` and `UI`.

### Usasge

So to use a Class `MyClass` from `SomeProject.Core` you would have three possibilities to use it.

1. using Direcitve

`using SomeProject.Core;`

calling it with `MyClass`

2. Calling it with the entire Namespace

`SomeProject.Core.MyClass`

3. Explicite using Directive (rarely used, but maybe useful for longe namespaces)

`using AnyName = SomeProject.Core;`

call `MyClass` with `AnyName.MyClass`

So i guess thats it for the moment.. if i forgot anything just tell me in the comments